How to inspect the body of a function (without it's signiture)
How can a function's body be inspected in Python?
def main():

    def example_function():
        x = 4
        y = 3
        if x + y < 6:
            print("Test")
        print("Example")

    import inspect
    print(inspect.getsource(example_function))

main()

This prints out:
    def example_function():
        x = 4
        y = 3
        if x + y < 6:
            print("Test")
        print("Example")

Is there a robust way of only printing the function body without it's signature?
Which would only output:
        x = 4
        y = 3
        if x + y < 6:
            print("Test")
        print("Example")

In most cases skipping the first line would be sufficient, but it's not guaranteed the function signature isn't multi-line so a way to skip any signature would be better.

Instead of skipping first line, you could split the output on the first occuring colon ":", because there should never be a colon in the name of the function or in the arguments (that I know of). So if the api doesnt work, it would be like print(inspect.getsource(example_function).split(':')[1]

@ee-4-me That will break easily with : appearing as a type hint or as part of a default value of a string. A more robust solution would be to parse the code into AST. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78445952/6890912

Ahh, didn't thing about default values for strings, yeah good point thanks

@ee-4-me Actually on second thought, not just strings, but also dicts, slices, lambda functions and assignment expressions, etc.
